# I want to access the usage time of all applications. How do i program this in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want an application that can track the usage time of all my application. How can i implement this in flutter? What packages to use?

Answer (score 3):

For someone who is still looking for answer, For ios as @Sahandevs, you need to do some tricks which could be rejected by apple, but for android there are package available to achieve this feature.

Like:

1- [device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps)

2 - [app_usage](https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage)

Hope, this will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [How to create a Service which continuously monitors app usage information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416610/how-to-create-a-service-which-continuously-monitors-app-usage-information) to create a service in android to track installed apps and use flutter method channel to retrieve data from java (or kotlin) to your flutter app. [Learn More](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

in iOS though, i think you need to do some tricks that maybe will be rejected by apple. see this links for more info:

- [Tracking an App's running time iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373646/tracking-an-apps-running-time-ios)